# Finding a subset whose sum is zero

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have an Excel file containing two rows, one containing numbers, another having ID, serial number basically.
Now, these numbers are both positive and negative. I have to find if there exists a subset whose sum is zero. If yes, then the IDs of the element of the subsets whose sum is zero. It would be awesome if I could also find all subsets smaller than a number, say 3 or 4.
The most important part is that I want the IDs of the numbers.

```
def subset_sum_exists(numbers, target):
    n = len(numbers)
    # Initialize a 2D array with size (n+1) * (target+1)
    dp = [[False for _ in range(target + 1)] for _ in range(n + 1)]
    # Initialize the first column with true
    for i in range(n + 1):
        dp[i][0] = True
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, target + 1):
            # if j is less than current number
            if j < numbers[i - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j]
            # if j is greater or equal than current number
            if j >= numbers[i - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] or dp[i - 1][j - numbers[i - 1]]
    # return the last element
    return dp[n][target]
```

This code should at least tell me if such a subset exists or not, but seems like there is some error in this. For `target = 0`, it always says true. For others, it gives an error.

numbers = [6, 20, 54, 93, -54, -26]

Comment: Can you show a simple representation of your data in the question? Otherwise it's impossible to reproduce your error

Comment: numbers =[6, 20, 54, 93, -54, -26]